# PHP eBay API Object Values

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am working with the eBay API, and am using GetSingleItem to retrieve eBay item data. From this data I want to extract the price from the returned object:

```
DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\AmountType Object
            (
                [values:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType:private] => Array
                    (
                        [currencyID] => USD
                        [value] => 19.99
                    )

                [attachment:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType:private] => Array
                    (
                        [data] =>
                        [mimeType] =>
                    )

            )
```

I have tried converting the object to an array, I have tried using obj->values->value.
How can I retrieve the price data (19.99) from the value array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to do `$item->CurrentPrice->value`. For example:

`$response = $service->getSingleItem($request);
$item = $response->Item;
$item->CurrentPrice->value;`

Just in case you are not aware there is an [example of using the SDK for calling GetSingleItem](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/shopping/02-get-single-item.php).

Comment: My error was using upper case V for value and not $item->CurrentPrice->value as you stated. Thanks for your help.